# Can I get output of subprocess.Popen including my inputs

Tags: python, subprocess

I use Python to check output of other Python scripts.
In my script I need to run another Python script and get the output **including input**.
The script also shouldn't run longer than 5 seconds because the scripts may cointain infinitive loop.
My scripts looks like:

```
import subprocess

file = "file.py"

p1 = subprocess.Popen(['python', file],stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, encoding="utf-8")


try:
    stdout, stderr = p1.communicate(input="1\n2\n",timeout=5)
    print(stdout, stderr)
except:
    p1.kill()
    print("Error")
```

file.py:

```
print("Hello world")
a = input("Enter the text: ")
b = input("Enter the second text: ")

print(a,b)
```

And the output is:

> Hello world
>
> Enter the text: Enter the second text: 1 2

It should be:

> Hello world
>
> Enter the text: 1
>
> Enter the second text: 2
>
> 1 2

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Inputs _aren't_ part of output. They only look that way in a terminal because of "local echo", but that's a terminal feature, not something that's really there in stdout or stderr.

Answer (score 1):

Using only `communicate` is a bit tricky.

So, the better way that I would suggest is to use `loop` and `readline()` to send an input and print an output time step by time step from the target python script instead.

The example code:

```
# use with to closes the pipes and waits subprocess to exit.
with subprocess.Popen(['python', file], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, bufsize=1) as cat:
    # list of your input
    input_string = ['1', '2']
    for string in input_string:
        print(string, file=cat.stdin, flush=True)
        print(cat.stdout.readline(), end='')
```

Another option is to use `check_output()`:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(
                      ['python', file],
                      input="\n".join(['1', '2']),
                      text=True)
print(output, end='')
```

Also, the target file (i.e. `file.py`) requires modification a bit to handle input time step by time step:

```
i = 0
input_list = list()
# depend on how many your inputs
while i < 2:
    inp = input("Enter the text: ")
    print(inp)
    input_list.append(inp)
    time.sleep(1)
    i += 1

print(input_list)
```

And this is the output:

> ```
> > Enter the text: 1
> > Enter the text: 2 
> > ['1', '2']
> ```

Comment: I can't change file.py because it will depend on the user. Anyway thank you so much.